# Loop through Excel files and copy correct range in a separate file with C#

Tags: c#, excel

**Intro:**
Today I have decided to make an Excel automatization task with C#. This is probably the first time I am doing something like this, thus the problems are plenty.

**The task:**
Pretty much, the idea is the following - I have 4 excel files in folder `strPath`. I have to loop through all of them and make a file called `Report.xlsx` in the same folder, with the information from those files.

The information, that I need is anything, below row 9. Thus, the first row to copy is row number 10. That is why, the first file I loop for is saved as Report, and the `bMakeOnce` value is changed. After the first file is looped and saved As, I start entering into the else condition. There I locate the last used row of the XL files and I try to copy the range into the sheetReport.

**The questions:**

1. First of all - any ideas for code improvement;
2. Whenever I am looping through the files I get the following picture telling me that each of the looping file is opened already.
   [image]
3. Any good idea how to do the range copy better? Currently, I simply try to put the copied range on every 200+n line, to avoid some confusion for me.
4. Any idea why I do not get anything in the sheetReport, except for the first file?

The code I am using (initially, for the current goto Github below):

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;
     using System.IO;
     using System.Reflection;
     using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
     using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string strPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\..\..\"));
            string[] strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strPath);
            Excel.Application excel = null;
            bool bMakeOnce = true;

            int intFirstLine = 10;
            int intLastColumn = 50;
            int lastRow;
            int lastRowReport;

            Excel.Workbook wkbReport = null;
            string strWkbReportPath;
            int n = 0;

            foreach (string strFile in strFiles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(strFile);
                Excel.Workbook wkb = null;
                Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
                Excel.Worksheet sheetReport = null;

                Excel.Range rngLast = null;
                Excel.Range rngLastReport = null;
                Excel.Range rngToCopy = null;
                Excel.Range rngDestination = null;

                excel = new Excel.Application();
                excel.Visible = true;

                wkb = OpenBook(excel, strFile);
                if (bMakeOnce)
                {
                    bMakeOnce = false;
                    strWkbReportPath = wkb.Path + "\\" + "Report.xlsx";
                    wkb.SaveAs(strWkbReportPath);
                    wkbReport = OpenBook(excel, strWkbReportPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    wkb = OpenBook(excel, strFile);
                    sheetReport = wkbReport.Worksheets[1];
                    sheet = wkb.Worksheets[1];
                    n++;
                    rngLastReport = sheetReport.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
                    rngLast = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);

                    rngToCopy = sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[intFirstLine, 1], sheet.Cells[rngLast.Row, intLastColumn]];
                    int size = rngToCopy.Rows.Count;
                    Console.WriteLine(size);

                    rngDestination = sheetReport.Range[sheetReport.Cells[200 * n, 1], sheetReport.Cells[200 * n + size, intLastColumn]];

                    rngToCopy.Copy(rngDestination);
                    //rngDestination.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll);
                }
            }
            wkbReport.Close(false);
            excel.Quit();
        }

        public static Excel.Workbook OpenBook(Excel.Application excelInstance, string fileName, bool readOnly = false, bool editable = true, bool updateLinks = true)
        {
            Excel.Workbook book = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(
                fileName, updateLinks, readOnly,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, editable, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            return book;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As this is a whole piece of working code, you might get a more detailed analysis by posting this question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @Carrosive - thanks, I have considered this, but its not definitely working as it should be. Its somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Vatyata That's fair; it was the request for general improvements that through me off.

Comment: @Carrosive Once I am ready, I would probably set it through there as well, actually in the last hour I have achieved some progress.

Comment: I have put it in CodeReview here - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/153054/revisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works somehow, producing what I want:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string strPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\..\..\"));
        string[] strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strPath);
        Excel.Application excel = null;
        bool bMakeOnce = true;
        string strReportName = "Report.xlsx";
        int intFirstLine = 10;
        int intLastColumn = 50;
        int lastRow;
        int lastRowReport;
        int intTotalRows;

        Excel.Workbook wkbReport = null;
        string strWkbReportPath;
        int n = 0;

        excel = new Excel.Application();
        excel.Visible = true;

        foreach (string strFile in strFiles)
        {
            if (strFile.Contains(strReportName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(strReportName + " is deleted.");
                File.Delete(strFile);
            }
        }

        foreach (string strFile in strFiles)
        {
            if (strFile.Contains(strReportName))
            {
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(strFile);
            Excel.Workbook wkb = null;
            Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
            Excel.Worksheet sheetReport = null;
            Excel.Range rngLastReport = null;
            Excel.Range rngToCopy = null;

            wkb = Open(excel, strFile);
            if (bMakeOnce)
            {
                bMakeOnce = false;
                strWkbReportPath = wkb.Path + "\\" + strReportName;
                wkb.SaveAs(strWkbReportPath);
                wkb.Close();
                wkbReport = Open(excel, strWkbReportPath);
            }
            else
            {   
                sheetReport = wkbReport.Worksheets[1];
                sheet = wkb.Worksheets[1];

                //lastRow = sheet.Cells[1, 3].get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;

                intTotalRows = sheet.Rows.Count;
                lastRow = sheet.Cells[intTotalRows, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
                lastRowReport = sheetReport.Cells[intTotalRows, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;

                //lastRowReport = sheetReport.Cells[intTotalRows, 1].get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
                //lastRowReport = sheetReport.Cells[intTotalRows, intTotalRows.End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp]].Row;
                n++;

                rngToCopy = sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[intFirstLine,1],sheet.Cells[lastRow, intLastColumn]];
                int size = rngToCopy.Rows.Count;
                rngLastReport = sheetReport.Range[sheetReport.Cells[lastRowReport+1, 1], sheetReport.Cells[lastRowReport + 1+size, intLastColumn]];

                rngToCopy.Copy(rngLastReport);
                wkb.Close(false);
            }
        }
        wkbReport.Close(true);
        excel.Quit();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
    }

    public static Excel.Workbook Open(Excel.Application excelInstance, string fileName, bool readOnly = false, bool editable = true, bool updateLinks = true)
    {
        Excel.Workbook book = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(
            fileName, updateLinks, readOnly,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, editable, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        return book;
    }
    //public static Excel.Workbook OpenBook(Excel.Application excelInstance, string fileName, bool readOnly = false, bool editable = true, bool updateLinks = true)
    //{
    //    Excel.Workbook book = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(
    //        fileName, updateLinks, readOnly,
    //        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    //        Type.Missing, editable, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    //        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    //    return book;
    //}

}
```

Thus, I have put it codeReview here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153054/loop-through-excel-files-and-copy-correct-range-in-a-separate-file